# How to create my work object and keep it up to date?

Tags: c#

Let's simply say I add, edit and delete some expenses in a database. Every class that works with these expenses should work with an object which represents a particular expense. Whenever a user enters some data into a form or data gets loaded, I want this expenses to be encapsulated in an custom object that should be kept up to date. So what is the best way to create my expense object?

I thought that whenever the value of a textbox, combobox and what not changes I let the eventhandler update the corresponding property of my expense object.

My other idea was, that whenever there is work to be done on a particular expense a method is called which updates the object. I don't like this idea because it's not intuitive.

Are there better ways to archive that goal of an always up to date object?

Edit:
Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I already use Entity Framework. For example if I load some data from a database, I get an Entity Framework Object (**EFO**). I want the data from that object in my own object(**MOO**). So I convert it to **MOO**. Then, when I open a Form, I want that form to display the data of **MOO**. When a user creates an a new expense he creates **MOO**. If he edits an expense, he edits **MOO**. When I pass **MOO** to my DataAdapterClass for upload, then it gets converted back to an **EFO**. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you specifically asking about how to keep your "MOO" updated based on what is happening in the UI?

If you use WPF, this is basically what you'd use databinding for - you would bind your controls to MOO properties and let the bindings keep the two in sync.

Comment: Databinding seems to be exactly what I looked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a mapper between your C# code and the database retrieval/inserting functionality that does the mapping to and from objects.
I recommend using Entity Framework for this as this is the industry standard provided by Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx